# Error compiling Visual Studio solution generated by Qt qbs

Tags: qt, qbs

I am using Qt qbs to generate Visual Studio solution for my new project. I use QtCreator to create a new qbs-based project, then use the command line below to generate the .sln file:

```
qbs generate -g visualstudio2015 profile:qt595 config:Release
```

Of cause, I've generated the qt595 profile for qbs.

Then I open the sln file in my Visual Studio 2015, press Ctrl+Shift+B to start building. VS complains:

```
EXEC : error : Unexpected command line parameter 'Release'.
```

I opened the property of the project "qbs-generate", and found some thing goes wrong. The NMake command is as below:

```
$(QbsGenerateCommandLine) Release qbs.profile:qt595
```

which obviously has an unneeded parameter "Release", that's why VS complained.

So, how can I overcome this problem? I tried remove "Release" manually. VS built successfully that time, however the solution was generated again and after reloading the "Release" came back!

My Qt's version is 5.9.5, qbs is 1.11.0, and my operation system is Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in qbs 1.11.1; see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-1303. Please upgrade.

Comment: Well, wherever you got your current qbs from, get the new version from that source. E.g. if it was the Qt installer, upgrade the Creator package there etc.